# Unix script for masking sensitive data in the log files?

Tags: perl, unix, sed, awk

I have to write a script which will mask the sensitive data in the log files. I am confused how to implement this? Which option will be best for doing the same:

- Using AWK
- Using SED
- Using SED,AWK
- Using PERL
- Using simple file read and searching logic.

If you have any suggestions then please share.

```
Input File:
Name  Jack
Add   New York
Phone 333-333-3434

Output File:
Name   Jack
Add    New York
Phone  XXX-XXX-XXXX
```

I tried this using awk:

```
cat $HOME_DIR/testdata.dat | awk 'BEGIN{ 
    i=1; 
    FS=" "; 
} 
{ 
    for (i = 1; i < NF; i++) { 
        fld = $(i); 
        if( fld == "PHONE") { 
            printf ("%s$%s", $(i),$(i+1)); 
        } 
        else if( fld == "PIN") { 
            printf ("%s$%s", $(i),$(i+1)); 
        } 
        else if( fld == "DOB") { 
            printf ("%s$%s", $(i),$(i+1)); 
        } else { 
            printf ("%s", $(i)); 
        } 
    } 
    printf ("\n"); 
} 
END{ 
    i=1 
}' > $HOME_DIR/testdataupd.dat
```

Comment: Your question should show research effort.

Comment: `perl -ple 's/^phone\s+\K[\pN-]+$/XXX-XXX-XXXX/i' inputfile > outputfile`

Comment: I tried this using awk:
cat $HOME_DIR/testdata.dat | awk 'BEGIN{
i=1;
FS=" ";
}
{
 
 for (i = 1; i < NF; i++)
 {
  fld = $(i);
  if( fld == "PHONE")
  {
   printf ("%s$%s", $(i),$(i+1));
  }
  else if( fld == "PIN")
  {
   printf ("%s$%s", $(i),$(i+1));
  }
  else if( fld == "DOB")
  {
   printf ("%s$%s", $(i),$(i+1));
  }
  else
  {
   printf ("%s", $(i));
  }
 }
 printf ("\n");
}
END{
i=1
}' > $HOME_DIR/testdataupd.dat

Now i am writing another script for updating testdataupd.dat file finding $ sign.

Let me know if anything more you need.

Comment: @Nitin You should add that information to your question using the edit feature, not post it in a comment.

Comment: First off, setting `i = 1` in the `BEGIN` block is wasted since the `for` loop initializes it for you. Second, setting `i = 1` in the `END` block does nothing at all. Third, it looks like your script might do exactly what you want except that you're printing the phone number as-is instead of printing "XXX-XXX-XXXX". Fourth, AWK accepts filenames as arguments, there's no need for `cat`.

Comment: @TLP thank i will take care of it. but its now in my question. May be someone did it thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way using `awk`. When found words `phone`, `dob` or `pin` at the beginning of the line (ignoring case) substitute in second field all characters but `-` with `X`. The `print` command is executed for every line.

```
awk '
    BEGIN { 
        IGNORECASE = 1
    }
    $1 ~ /^(phone|dob|pin)$/ {
        gsub( /[^-]/, "X", $2 )
    }
    { print }
' $HOME_DIR/testdata.dat >$HOME_DIR/testdataupd.dat
```

Comment: I really want to thanks you for this. This logic helped me what i want to achieve. And good news is just now i accomplished what i wanted to do :). thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a 90% answer, does not format the Xs as you asked though.

```
sed -re 's/(Phone )(([0-9]+)-?)*/\1xxxxx/g'
```

for more fields

```
sed -r -e 's/(Phone )(([0-9]+)-?)*/\1xxxxx/g' -e 's/regexp-to-search-for/replacement-pattern/g' …
```

note: you can replace / with and character you like as long as it is same all 3 times  e.g. `s~regexp~rep~g`

Comment: How about if we can use this in awk? what do you say?

Also i have 5 fields which i need to mask it. So in that shall we make a array of those fields and use this above sed command to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^Phone\|^DOB\|^Pin/!b;h;s/\S*\s*//;s/[^-]/X/g;H;x;s/\(\S*\)\n\(\S*\)/\2/' file
```

Explanation:

- `/^Phone\|^DOB\|^Pin/!b` only process lines beginning `Phone`, `DOB` or `Pin` (add more here)
- `h` copy pattern space (PS) to hold space (HS) i.e. make a copy of the current line.
- `s/\S*\s*//` delete the first first field and following white space.
- `s/[^-]/X/g` replace all occurrences of `-`'s with `X`'s in the remaining field.
- `H` append a newline and then the PS to the HS.
- `x` swap HS with PS
- `s/\(\S*\)\n\(\S*\)/\2/` replace the original second field with the amended one.

Comment: tested does not work, added -e still does not work. `sed: -e expression #1, char 29: unknown command: `\'`

Comment: @potong What do you mean 2nd version? I have `GNU sed version 4.2.1`

Comment: @richard sorry I thought perhaps that the version of sed you were using didn't understand `\S` or `\s`, so I provided another solution. But a `\\` had somehow crept in to my original solution and was causing your problem. Please use the above amended solution.

Comment: @potong +1 (comment) for fixing it, and it working. If you can explain it (in the answer) I will +1 the answer.