# How to print environment names with masked values on Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I want to print all environment variables on Linux using standard tools and bash. I need to see environment name and masked variable with the last 3 characters visible if variable length is greater than 5 (`qwerty` -> `***rty`), and masked value with 1 visible character if it's less than 5 (or equal to 5) (`zxc` -> `**c`).

Example:

```
FOO=qwerty
BAR=asdfghjkl
BAZ=zxc
```

I'm expecting this command to print:

```
FOO=***rty
BAR=******jkl
BAZ=**c
```

The length of original value and masked is the same here.

At the moment I tried to implement this using this `awk` command, but it's handles only some of these cases by replacing all word with 3 `*` and cut the value to the last 3 characters (I'm not really good with awk, so maybe it could be implemented better):

```
env | awk -F= '{ if(length($2)>5) {printf("%s=***%s\n", $1, substr($2, length($2)-2))} }'
```

Comment: This seems like you try to hide sensitive information (eg passwords, credit card numbers, ...). If this is the case, have a look at the following pages: [(SE) Is it secure to store passwords as environment variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12461484/8344060), [(U&L)Hiding Password in Shell Scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/212329/273492), [(IS) How to securely store credentials in a bash variables?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/150580)

Comment: @kvantour thanks, in my case I'm trying to just debug container deployment in development environment, where no really sensitive information could be printed, but I want to hide even these params

Comment: `perl -pe 's/(?<==)(.*)(.{3})$/ sprintf("%s%s", "*" x length($1), $2)/e'`

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11343665/unix-script-for-masking-sensitive-data-in-the-log-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution in pure `bash` might be:

```
#!/bin/bash

env |
while IFS='=' read -r name value; do
    n=$((${#value} > 5 ? -3 : ${#value} > 0 ? -1 : 0))
    head=${value:0:n}
    printf '%s=%s%s\n' "$name" "${head//?/'*'}" "${value:n}"
done
```

Note: In shell programming, reading lines by a `while read` loop is inefficient. I'm assuming the output issued by the `env` command is small enough that this inefficiency isn't significant. You shouldn't use this technique for large inputs.

Comment: You probably shouldn't, though - see [`while read` loop extremely slow compared to `cat`, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762625/bash-while-read-loop-extremely-slow-compared-to-cat-why)

Answer (score 1):

Try this script with awk gensub:

```
#!/bin/bash

env | awk -F= '{
  name=$1;
  value=$2;

  if (length(value) > 5) {
    mask=gensub(/./,"*","g",substr(value,1,length(value)-3));
    value=mask substr(value,length(value)-2);
  } else {
    mask=gensub(/./,"*","g",substr(value,1,length(value)-1));
    value=mask substr(value,length(value));
  }

  print name "=" value;
}'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be lazy and don't care about the correct amount of asterisks, you could just do:

```
$ env | sed 's/=\(...*\)\(...\)/=***\2/'
```

If the asterisks have to be the correct total, you could use awk. However, using the equal sign as a field delimiter is not the way forward as a single line might contain more than one equal sign:

```
$ env | awk '{i=index($0,"="); s=substr($0,i+1);l=length(s)}(l>5){x=substr(s,1,l-3); gsub(/./,"*",x); print substr($0,1,i) s1 substr(s,l-2); next}1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly more compact `awk` version that handles environment strings greater than 5-characters replacing all but the last three characters in the value with `'*'`. In the case of the string being 5-characters or less, all but the last character is replaced. That matches your example output, though you have not provided examples with 4 or 5 characters exactly.

Basically the `awk` script builds a `mask` of the correct number of `"***"` characters and a dynamic regular expression `re` of `"..."` with the number of replacement characters and calls `sub()` to make the replacement, e.g,

```bash
awk -F= '
{
  l = length($2)
  mask = ""
  re = ""
  for (i=0;i<(l>5?l-3:l-1);i++) {
    mask = mask "*"
    re = re "."
  }
  mask = "=" mask
  re = "=" re
  sub (re, mask)
  print
}' file
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ awk -F= '
> {
>   l = length($2)
>   mask = ""
>   re = ""
>   for (i=0;i<(l>5?l-3:l-1);i++) {
>     mask = mask "*"
>     re = re "."
>   }
>   mask = "=" mask
>   re = "=" re
>   sub (re, mask)
>   print
> }' << eof
> FOO=qwerty
> BAR=asdfghjkl
> BAZ=zxc
> eof
FOO=***rty
BAR=******jkl
BAZ=**c
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach pre-makes a string of `"*" x 2,400`, and replaces via `substr()`-ing instead of `regex`, so unless you have data values beyond `2,400` bytes/chars, this should suffice.

```
mawk 'BEGIN { FS = OFS = "="; _=(_=(_="*")_ _)_
              gsub(__,_,_) gsub(__,_,_); _ +=(_^= ___ = _)+_ } 
$NF = sprintf("%.*s%s",__ -=_^((_+_) <= (__ = length($NF))), ___, substr($NF, ++__))'
```

> 

```
FOO=***rty
BAR=******jkl
BAZ=**c
```